Can't connect headphones "org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationFailed" on arch linux
To begin with I am quite new to Linux although when I try and connect my bluetooth headphones (Crusher evo if that helps), I get this

org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationFailed

when in the pairing stage. It says "connected" then immediately disconnects.
If anyone knows the solution to this that would be amazing as I have spent the last week on and off trying to fix it.
System info: Running hyprland on Arch Linux
